# How to urllib.urlencode a dictionary within an array?

Tags: python, urllib, urlencode

I'm trying to urlencode this parameter:

```
params = {
                              "attachments": [
                                  {
                                      "title": "output.title",
                                      "text": "output.text",
                                  }
                              ]}

urllib.urlencode(params, True)
```

This is what I get:

```
attachments=%7B%27text%27%3A+%27output.text%27%2C+%27title%27%3A+%27output.title%27%7D
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
attachments=%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%20%22output.text%22%2C%20%22title%22%3A%22output.title%22%7D%5D
```

UPDATE:

I have noticed, if I disable dosec, I get something closer to what I need.

```
urllib.urlencode(params)

attachments=%5B%7B%27text%27%3A+%27output.text%27%2C+%27title%27%3A+%27output.title%27%7D%5D
```

But there are still differences %22% vs %27%

Comment: A dictionary has no order.

Comment: order doesn't matter. The encoding doesn't look the same to me.

Comment: Could you please strip down your code to what is necessary to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: How about now?  ..

Comment: Try `urllib.urlencode({key: json.dumps(value) for key, value in params.items()}, False)` (need to import `json`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `%22` is the double quote (`"`) while `%27` is the simple quote (`'`). And `urllib.urlencode` simply encode a dictionary or an sequence of two-elements tuple.

So here your dictionary has `attachement` as key, and has the following list of dictionaries as value:

```
                   val = [
                              {
                                  "title": "output.title",
                                  "text": "output.text",
                              }
                          ]
```

But for python, that list is **not** a string, so it uses its representation as a string (using simple quotes):

```
>>> str(val)
[{'text': 'output.text', 'title': 'output.title'}]
```

and then urlencode that string. If you want double quotes to be Json compatible, you should use the json module:

```
>>> json.dumps(val)
'[{"text": "output.text", "title": "output.title"}]'
```

Finally it would give:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({ k: json.dumps(v) for k,v in params.iteritems() })
'attachments=%5B%7B%22text%22%3A+%22output.text%22%2C+%22title%22%3A+%22output.title%22%7D%5D'
```

which is what you expected (apart from the order of items, but a dictionary is a hash and does not maintain order - use a sequence of pairs if you need order)

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary type represented like this,

```
>>> params = {
...                               "attachments": [
...                                   {
...                                       "title": "output.title",
...                                       "text": "output.text",
...                                   }
...                               ]}
>>> print params
{'attachments': [{'text': 'output.text', 'title': 'output.title'}]}
```

urllib.urlencode escaping that strings. so you have get "%27" which is html escape caracter of single quotation.

But you want to escaped to "%22" ( double quotation ).

If you want it, then you have not to use urlencode directly.

Try to use json dumps and encoding each item.

Like,

```
import urllib
import json


def myencode(dic):
    return urllib.urlencode({d: json.dumps(dic[d]) for d in dic})

params = {
                              "attachments": [
                                  {
                                      "title": "output.title",
                                      "text": "output.text",
                                  }
                              ]}

urllib.urlencode(params, True)

myencode(params)
```